# How to export xls files to txt files reading them from folder (Visual Basic)?

Tags: excel, vba, file, directory, export

I am trying to read files *.xls from u:\test folder. There is one sheet in every file. I want to copy cell B1 and to paste it into new file to A1. Then I want to copy range B1:B57 and to paste it into the new file/sheet to B1:B57. Then I want to copy range K1:U57 and copy (the values only) to the new file/sheet C1 location. I am doing this in Visual Basic 6 and I have problem to find out how to use the range function... I tried to activated and select the sheet(1). Then I wanted to use the command `Set SrchRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1))`. I got error 1004 Application defined or object defined error. Here on this line. If I would successed to select/copy/paste the cell areas to new file/sheet, then I would like to save the current file as txt, given the .txt extenssion. How to correct this code to reach the goal?

```
Sub FromExcelToNpad()
    'export activesheet as txt file
    Dim my_files As String
    Dim folder_path As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, NewWB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SrcRange As Range
    folder_path = "u:\test"
    my_files = Dir(folder_path & "\*.xls", vbDirectory)
    Do While my_files <> vbNullString
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folder_path & "\" & my_files)
       Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
       Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add
       ws.Activate
       ws.Select
       Set SrchRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1))
       wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
       wb.Close True
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
       my_files = Dir()
    Loop
   
End Sub
```

**Update**
The range and cells are copied:

```
Dim my_files As String
Dim folder_path As String
Dim wb As Workbook, NewWB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
folder_path = "u:\test"
my_files = Dir(folder_path & "\*.xls", vbDirectory)
Do While my_files <> vbNullString
   Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folder_path & "\" & my_files)
   Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
   Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add
   ws.Range("B1").Copy NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
   ws.Range("B3:B57").Copy NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A3:A57")
   ws.Range("K1:U57").Copy
   NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("B1:L57").PasteSpecial xlValues
   wb.Close True
   With NewWB
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs Filename:=folder_path & "\" & my_files, FileFormat:=xlText
        .Close True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   End With
   wb.Save
   my_files = Dir()
Loop
```

I am trying to save the file as .txt . I have error Run time error - automation error. Also there is a dialog asking me if I want to save data from a "page". How to turn this off?

Comment: You are doing this in `Visual Basic 6` or `VBA`? That's not clear and those are 2 totally different approaches. Please clarify which one it is.

Comment: Change `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1))` to `ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)` • You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Visual Basic. I mean, the language of Visual Basic is VBA?

Comment: @Peh: Thank you. It passed. But the copy command does not copy the selected area to the destination. `Set SrchRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)
       SrchRange.Copy NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")`

Comment: Well in your text you say you want to copy Cell B1 To A1. So do that `ws.Range("B1").Copy NewWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")` Do the same with the other ranges you want to copy. • You can remove the `ws.Activate` and `ws.Select` lines they are not needed.

Comment: @Peh. May you please check the updated code and help me to save the file?

Comment: Check the content of `my_files` it is probably ending as `.xls` and needs to be changed to `.txt` • Since you did not change anything in `wb` you don't need to save it on closing. Change `wb.Close True` to `wb.Close False`. And remove `wb.Save` in the end. You cannot save a workbook that you already closed before.

Comment: @Peh: I replaced it `my_files = Replace(my_files, ".xls", ".txt")` but still there is the runtime error. Yet there is empty file `1.txt` has been created on disk.

Comment: In which line do you get the error? In `.SaveAs`? Did you change both `.Close True` to `.Close False` and remove the `wb.Save`?

Comment: @Peh: Yes, the error is on the line with .Save() . Now updated not to save the temporal file.

Comment: In this line `wb.Save`? As I told you should remove it. You cannot save `wb` because you alreay closed it with `wb.Close`.

Comment: Ah. Ok. So now I have removed it and tested it. I have found out that the file 1.xls has been overwritten with no data. So thïs is why the 1.txt has been empty. Thank you. It works now.